# c# Group linq results into a new list of a particular class

Tags: c#

How do I need to write to iterate through the results of each of those three initial lists in order to return a single List. Title is the grouping value.

```
var invoiced = new List<Anonim> 
{ 
new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 20},
new Anonim {Category = 2, Title = "Accounting", Amount = 10}
}
var settled = new List<Anonim> {
new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 10}
}
var credit = new List<Anonim> {
new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 30},
new Anonim {Category = 2, Title = "Accounting", Amount = 20}
}


var result = new List<Result> {
new Result {Title = credit.Title, Invoiced = invoiced.Amount, Settled = settled.Amount, SumAmount = credit.Amount + settled.Amount + invoiced.Amount },
new Result {Title = credit.Title, Invoiced = invoiced.Amount, Settled = settled.Amount, SumAmount = credit.Amount + settled.Amount + invoiced.Amount }
}


public class Result
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Credit { get; set; }
    public decimal Invoiced { get; set; }
    public decimal Settled { get; set; }
    public decimal SumAmount { get; set; }
}

public class Anonim { 
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

SumAmount is the sum of Invoiced, settled, credit of each item

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the `Category` property?

Comment: What is the difference between Legal and Accounting.  Not clear in posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you want to happen, but assuming you want to group by the `Title` property, here's one method. First you project each list into the `Result` class, making sure to set the relevant properties for each one, union them together into a big list and then group them to get the totals:

```
var groupedResults = invoiced.Select(i => new Result
{
    Title = i.Title,
    Invoiced = i.Amount
}).Union(settled.Select(i => new Result
{
    Title = i.Title,
    Settled = i.Amount
})).Union(credit.Select(i => new Result
{
    Title = i.Title,
    Credit = i.Amount
}));

var result = groupedResults
    .GroupBy(r => r.Title)
    .Select(g => new Result
    {
        Title = g.Key,
        Invoiced = g.Sum(r => r.Invoiced),
        Settled = g.Sum(r => r.Settled),
        Credit = g.Sum(r => r.Credit),
        SumAmount = g.Sum(r => r.Invoiced+r.Settled+r.Credit)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution goes into what I want to achieve and I've added into my linqpad solution and returns a "NotSupportedExpection: Types in Union or Concat have members assigned in different order."

Comment: Not sure why you get that, I checked the code in LinqPad and it gives me a valid result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byeRQ.png).

Comment: You are correct, I might have been made some mistakes on converting into the final solution, because invoiced, settled, or creditors are IQueryable<anonymous type>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is something you want, however this is inefficient due to numerous collection traversals. Maybe @DavidG solution will be more performant.

```
var groupedSum = invoiced.Union(settled).Union(credit).GroupBy(g => g.Title).Select(g => new Result
{ 
    Title = g.Key,
    Credit = credit.Where(c => c.Title == g.Key).Sum(c => c.Amount),
    Settled = settled.Where(c => c.Title == g.Key).Sum(c => c.Amount),
    Invoiced = invoiced.Where(c => c.Title == g.Key).Sum(c => c.Amount),
    SumAmount = g.Sum(i => i.Amount)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest I can find :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication73
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Anonim> invoiced = new List<Anonim> 
            { 
                new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 20},
                new Anonim {Category = 2, Title = "Accounting", Amount = 10}
            };

            List<Anonim> settled = new List<Anonim> {
                new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 10}
            };

            List<Anonim> credit = new List<Anonim> {
                new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 30},
                new Anonim {Category = 2, Title = "Accounting", Amount = 20}
            };

            List<Result> results = new List<Result>();


            List<string> titles = invoiced.Select(x => x.Title).ToList();
            titles.AddRange(settled.Select(x => x.Title).ToList());
            titles.AddRange(credit.Select(x => x.Title).ToList();
            titles = titles.Distinct().ToList();


            foreach(string title in titles)
            {
                Result newResult = new Result();
                results.Add(new Result);

                newResult.Title = title;
                newResult.Credit = credit.Where(x => x.Title == title).Sum(x => x.Amount);
                newResult.Invoiced = invoiced.Where(x => x.Title == title).Sum(x => x.Amount);
                newResult.Settled = settled.Where(x => x.Title == title).Sum(x => x.Amount);
                newResult.SumAmount = newResult.Credit + newResult.Invoiced + newResult.Settled;
            }

        }

    }
    public class Result
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Credit { get; set; }
        public decimal Invoiced { get; set; }
        public decimal Settled { get; set; }
        public decimal SumAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Anonim
    {
        public int Category { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Someone really likes to create console applications! :)

Comment: I was just joking about the "73" :) Also, have you tried LinqPad? Much faster for prototyping code like this.

Comment: Why go to another language when the OP needs c#.  Another joke?

Comment: I'm confused. LinqPad uses C#

Comment: Isn't LinqPad a c# simulator and not the real thing?

Comment: No, it uses the real C# compiler. Seriously give it a go, you won't regret it. There's another open source one too, but for the life of me I can't remember the name.

Comment: @jdweng LinqPad is really a good tool, DavidG was not joking when it recommended it. I'm currently using it to convert a lot of SQL procedures into linq statements, it shows you the sql statement generated behind. Allows you to write C# Programs, only statements or expressions. Simple for debugging.

Comment: Wiki says followng : "It is used to interactively query SQL databases (among other data sources such as OData or WCF Data Services) using LINQ, as well as interactively writing C# code without the need for an IDE."  It is not the real thing.  Just help write SQL queries and this request has nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var invoiced = new List<Anonim> 
                { 
                new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 20},
                new Anonim {Category = 2, Title = "Accounting", Amount = 10}
                };
            var settled = new List<Anonim> {
                new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 10}
                };
            List<Anonim> credit = new List<Anonim> {
                new Anonim {Category = 1, Title = "Legal", Amount = 30},
                new Anonim {Category = 2, Title = "Accounting", Amount = 20}
                };

            List<Result> x = new List<Result>();
            x.AddRange(invoiced.Select(y => new Result { Title = y.Title, Invoiced = y.Amount }));
            x.AddRange(settled.Select(y => new Result { Title = y.Title, Invoiced = y.Amount }));
            x.AddRange(credit.Select(y => new Result { Title = y.Title, Invoiced = y.Amount }));
```

var FinalList = x.GroupBy(a => a.Title).Select(Fn => new Result   {
            Title =Fn.Key,
            Invoiced = Fn.Sum(a => a.Invoiced),``
            Settled = Fn.Sum(a => a.Settled),
            Credit = Fn.Sum(a => a.Credit),
            SumAmount = Fn.Sum(a => a.Invoiced + a.Settled + a.Credit)
    });